# Kernel Panic on Shutdown

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic, firmware-password

For a few weeks, every time I shutdown my laptop, It immediately reboots and displays a kernel panic error. I haven't been able to cleanly shut down for some time. The machine is a 15" Retina Macbook Pro running 10.8.2

I have no peripherals attached. I have repaired the disk and disk permissions. I have been trying to run the Apple Hardware Test, but it will not run with a firmware password enabled. When I disable the firmware password from the recovery partition and reboot, the same kernel panic occurs, and the change of setting does not take effect, i.e. the firmware password remains intact, I cannot disable it. This is frustrating to say the least.

Here is one of the kernel panic logs: http://pastebin.com/waAmUYV7

Any ideas?

Edit: I have reset the SMC and uninstalled all programs that were using non-apple kexts. The problem persists. Here is an updated error log http://pastebin.com/q23pmK91

Comment: Try uninstalling the Telestream products.

Comment: I would also try to reset your SMC: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these worked. I have added some more info.